# Erro no JSON com acentos

Tags: php, html, ajax, json

Estou tendo problemas com o meu `JSON`, o erro é acentuação, o `JSON` permite? se ele permite, como posso fazer para mostrar, o que vai receber o `JSON` precisa que ele esteja normal, com acentos e tudo..

### MEU JSON:

```
{
    "id": "addCTE",
    "status": "Em Digita\u00e7\u00e3o",
    "chaveDeAcesso": "000001",
    "versaoXML": "2.0",
    "modelo": "1",
    "serie": "2",
    "numero": "3",
    "dataHoraEmissao": "2015-08-12",
    "cfop": "4",
    "naturezaDaOperacao": "5",
    "modal": "aquaviario",
    "tipoServico": "subcontratacao",
    "finalidadeDeEmissao": "cte_normal",
    "formaDeEmissao": "contingencia_fsda",
    "formaDePagamento": "pago",
    "formatoDeImpressaoDoDACTE": "retrato",
    "chaveAcessoDoCteReferenciado": "5",
    "localDeEmissaoCTeUF": "SP",
    "localDeEmissaoCTeMunicipio": "S\u00e3o Paulo",
    "localDeInicioDaPrestacaoUF": "SC",
    "localDeInicioDaPrestacaoMunicipio": "Salete",
    "localTerminoDaPrestacaoUF": "RJ",
    "localTerminoDaPrestacaoMunicipio": "Rio de Janeiro",
    "caracteristicaAddDoTransporte": "",
    "caracteristicaAddDoServico": "",
    "funcionarioEmissor": "",
    "municipioDeOrigemParaCalculoFrete": "",
    "municipioDeDestinoParaCalculoFrete": "",
    "codigoDaRotaDeEntrega": "",
    "fluxoDeCargaOrigem": "",
    "fluxoDeCargaDestino": "",
    "previsao_data": "",
    "previsao_hora": "",
    "detalhesDadosRetirada": ""
}
```

No lugar dos acentos, está o código, por exemplo, a palavra `Digitação` está exibindo `Digita\u00e7\u00e3o`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você "desconverter" o JSON, você irá escolher um "charset", pois como está, está apenas "unicode". Acredito que o que você esteja usando seja o Latin-1, ou ISO-8859-1.

```
\u00e7 = ç
```

`\u` de *unicode*, e `00e7` é o valor do caractere.